# cmd.executescalar() works but throws ORA-25191 Exception

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, oraclecommand

my Code is working, the function gives me the correct Select count (*) value but anyway, it throws an ORA-25191 Exception - Cannot reference overflow table of an index-organized table tips,
at retVal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Since I use the function very often, the exceptions slow down my program tremendously.

```
 private int getSelectCountQueryOracle(string Sqlquery)
        {
            try
            {
                int retVal = 0;
                using (DataTable dataCount = new DataTable())
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Sqlquery))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = oraCon;

                        using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
                        {
                            retVal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return retVal;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptionProtocol("Count Function", ex.ToString());
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

This function is called in a `foreach` loop

```
    // function call in foreach loop which goes through tablenames
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTbl.Rows)
                    {...    
                     tableNameFromRow = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();                                 
                     tableRows=getSelectCountQueryOracle("select count(*) as 'count' from " +tableNameFromRow);
                     tableColumns = getSelectCountQueryOracle("SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='" + tableNameFromRow + "'");
                     ...}
```

`dataTbl.rows` in this outer loop, in turn, comes from the query

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: What is the `sqlquery` string passed in to this function that causes the error?  My wild guess is that you are calling this function in a loop, that outer loop is getting a list of tables and building queries for each table, and that outer loop is failing to filter out IOT overflow tables.  But that's just speculation about code you haven't posted.

Comment: its just a select count(*) from 'table'. And Yes, the Function is in a foreach loop, which goes through a list of tablenames.

Comment: And where is the list of tables in that outer loop coming from?  I'd guess that piece of code isn't filtering out IOT overflow tables (potentially among other things).  Also, the function you posted is `getSelectCountQueryOracle` but the loop you posted is calling `getSelectCountQueryMSSQL`.  I assume your actual loop is calling the `Oracle` version (though I'm not sure why the Oracle and SQL Server versions would be different).

Comment: My guess is that list of tables should be coming from `connection.GetSchema("Tables")` but is actually coming from a query you coded yourself against the Oracle data dictionary that isn't filtering out IOT overflow tables (and might be missing other filters depending on the types of objects you're dealing with).

Comment: Wops, my bad, i copied the wrong Function in this thread. I have 2 different functions, one for oralce and one for mssql. the getSelectCountQueryMSSQL works w/o Exceptions. 

The tables comes from a query: "SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME"; which i fill in datatbl.

connection.GetSchema("Tables") is new for me, i will try this. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a database-agnostic API like ADO.Net, you would almost always want to use the API's framework to fetch metadata rather than writing custom queries against each database's metadata tables.  The various ADO.Net providers are much more likely to write data dictionary queries that handle all the various corner cases and are much more likely to be optimized than the queries you're likely to write.  So rather than writing your own query to populate the `dataTbl` data table, you'd want to use the [GetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections) method

```
DataTable dataTbl = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

If you want to keep your custom-coded data dictionary query for some reason, you'd need to filter out the IOT overflow tables since you can't query those directly.

```
select *
  from user_tables
 where iot_type IS NULL
    or iot_type != 'IOT_OVERFLOW'
```

Be aware, however, that there are likely to be other tables that you don't want to try to get a count from.  For example, the `dropped` column indicates whether a table has been dropped-- presumably, you don't want to count the number of rows in an object in the recycle bin.  So you'd want a `dropped = 'NO'` predicate as well.  And you can't do a `count(*)` on a nested table so you'd want to have a `nested = 'NO'` predicate as well if your schema happens to contain nested tables.  There are probably other corner cases depending on the exact set of features your particular schema makes use of that the developers of the provider have added code for that you'd have to deal with.

So I'd start with

```
select *
  from user_tables
 where (   iot_type IS NULL
        or iot_type != 'IOT_OVERFLOW')
   and dropped = 'NO'
   and nested = 'NO'
```

but know that you'll probably need/ want to add some additional filters depending on the specific features users make use of.  I'd certainly much rather let the fine folks that develop the ADO.Net provider worry about all those corner cases than to deal with finding all of them myself.

Taking a step back, though, I'd question why you're regularly doing a `count(*)` on every table in a schema and why you need an exact answer.  In most cases where you're doing counts, you're either doing a one-off where you don't much care how long it takes (i.e. a validation step after a migration) or approximate counts would be sufficient (i.e. getting a list of the biggest tables in the system in order to triage some effort or to track growth over time for projections) in which case you could just use the counts that are already stored in the data dictionary- `user_tables.num_rows`- from the last time that statistics were run.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, your answer helped me a lot.

I had the problem that some tables can have over 100 million fields and somehow they always the datatable.fill function throws memory exceptions. So I wanted to check how big they are before I fill the datatable. I simply cluster very large tables. I'm not sure if it's the smartest way, but it works w/o Exceptions.

Certainly a view in Oracle maybe would be better, but I'm new and don't have IDE rights for it. ^^,

Comment: @MartinHe - You'd almost certainly be better off just checking the `num_rows` column in `user_tables` (or `all_tables` or `dba_tables` depending on your privileges and what schemas you're interested in) rather than doing an explicit count.  There is no need to get an exact count of the number of rows in a table, just use the estimate the optimizer already has.  You could get the approximate count for every table in effectively no time.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_25191_cannot_reference_overflow_of_an_iot.htm) helped me to solve my problem.

I've changed my query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tables 
WHERE iot_type IS NULL OR iot_type != 'IOT_OVERFLOW' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```